# Getting "The multi-part identifier &RAUM.ID; could not be bound" SQL Error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT 
   r.BEZEICHNUNG AS BEZEICHNUNG, r.ID AS ID, ra.BEZEICHNUNG AS raumBEZEICHNUNG, 
   ra.ID AS raumID 
FROM RAUM r, RAUMATTRIBUTE ra 
INNER JOIN RAZUORDNUNG ON RAZUORDNUNG.RAUM_ID = RAUM.ID
INNER JOIN RAUMATTRIBUTE ON RAZUORDNUNG.RAUMATTRIBUTE_ID = RAUMATTRIBUTE.ID 
WHERE 
    RAUMKLASSE_ID = ISNULL(@Raumklasse_ID, RAUMKLASSE_ID) 
    AND STADT_ID = ISNULL(@Stadt_ID, STADT_ID) 
    AND GEBAEUDE_ID = ISNULL(@Gebaeude_ID, GEBAEUDE_ID) 
    AND REGION_ID = ISNULL(@Region_ID, REGION_ID)
```

If I use that query I get an error:

> The multi-part identifier &RAUM.ID; could not be bound.`

Why is that and how can I fix this?

Comment: PLease format the query so it's easier to read please and fits without scrolling, also you're mixing the old join syntax with the new one!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you've defined a table alias for your table `RAUM` (in the `FROM RAUM r`), you need to use that table alias - so use `r.ID` instead of `RAUM.ID`

```
SELECT 
   r.BEZEICHNUNG AS BEZEICHNUNG, r.ID AS ID, ra.BEZEICHNUNG AS raumBEZEICHNUNG, 
   ra.ID AS raumID 
FROM RAUM r, RAUMATTRIBUTE ra   <== you're defining "r" to be alias for "RAUM"
INNER JOIN RAZUORDNUNG ON RAZUORDNUNG.RAUM_ID = RAUM.ID  <== you need to use "r.ID"
......
```

Furthermore, I would **strongly suggest** you stop using the "old-style" JOIN of just comma-separating tables - use the proper ANSI INNER JOIN syntax instead:

```
SELECT 
   r.BEZEICHNUNG AS BEZEICHNUNG, r.ID AS ID, 
   ra.BEZEICHNUNG AS raumBEZEICHNUNG, ra.ID AS raumID 
FROM RAUM r
INNER JOIN RAZUORDNUNG rz ON rz.RAUM_ID = r.ID
INNER JOIN RAUMATTRIBUTE ra ON rz.RAUMATTRIBUTE_ID = ra.ID 
WHERE 
    RAUMKLASSE_ID = ISNULL(@Raumklasse_ID, RAUMKLASSE_ID) 
    AND STADT_ID = ISNULL(@Stadt_ID, STADT_ID) 
    AND GEBAEUDE_ID = ISNULL(@Gebaeude_ID, GEBAEUDE_ID) 
    AND REGION_ID = ISNULL(@Region_ID, REGION_ID)
```

You've not defined any JOIN condition between `RAUM r` and `RAUMATTRIBUTE ra` - so you basically get a CROSS JOIN (a cartesian product). Is that what you want? If not: define a proper JOIN condition in the `INNER JOIN` statement.

Comment: First Table: Raum: ID <pk>, Bezeichnung
Second Table: Razuordnung: ID<pk>, Raum_ID <fk>, Raumattribute_ID<fk>
Third Table: Raumattribute: ID<pk>, Bezeichnung

Comment: @Paks: ok, so that additional comma-separated `RAUMATTRIBUTE` was absolutely not needed at all. Updated my adapted query - does that return what you need?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have to change the first innner join to be **r.Id**:

```
    SELECT r.BEZEICHNUNG AS BEZEICHNUNG, r.ID AS ID, ra.BEZEICHNUNG AS raumBEZEICHNUNG, ra.ID AS raumID FROM RAUM r, RAUMATTRIBUTE ra 
INNER JOIN RAZUORDNUNG ON RAZUORDNUNG.RAUM_ID = r.ID
 INNER JOIN RAUMATTRIBUTE ON RAZUORDNUNG.RAUMATTRIBUTE_ID = RAUMATTRIBUTE.ID WHERE RAUMKLASSE_ID = ISNULL(@Raumklasse_ID, RAUMKLASSE_ID) AND STADT_ID = ISNULL(@Stadt_ID, STADT_ID) AND GEBAEUDE_ID = ISNULL(@Gebaeude_ID, GEBAEUDE_ID) AND REGION_ID = ISNULL(@Region_ID, REGION_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.
FROM RAUM r, RAUMATTRIBUTE ra 
INNER JOIN RAZUORDNUNG ON RAZUORDNUNG.RAUM_ID = RAUM.ID
.
```

RAUM is r is it not?

Comment: yes i know, and i tried INNER JOIN RAZUORDNUNG ON RAZUORDNUNG.RAUM_ID = r.ID, before i put my Question here, but get the same Error. I dont know why